# Prime elements in integrally closed extension of domains

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, prime-ideals

Let $R \subseteq S$ be an extension of integral domains such that $R$ is integrally closed in $S$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$.

> Is $PS$ always a prime ideal of $S$?

For classical examples of such extensions like localizations or constants inside a polynomial ring, the question clearly has a positive answer.

If it does not hold in general, does the restriction that the domains be valuation rings help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It does not hold in general: take $R=k[t]$, $S=k[x,y]$, with $R\hookrightarrow S$ by $t\mapsto xy$, and $P=(t)$.

Comment: @KConrad: There is the hypothesis that $R$ is integrally closed in $S$.

Comment: @abx oops, I missed that condition. I've now deleted my previous comment since it is not applicable.